# Break sentence to letters and rearrange them

Tags: string, break

I've try to break down a sentence to letters and rearrange them alphabetically.
Please see if i could improve this code in someway.
Kind regards

```
sen = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"  
smallest=[]  
re=''  

while len(sen) >0:  

    smallest.append( min(sen))
    print(ord(min(sen)))
    re=re+min(sen)
    sen = sen[:sen.index(min(sen))]+sen[sen.index(min(sen))+1:]
    counter+=1

print(smallest) #list
print(re) #string
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is exactly like sorting an array of number. You got a value for each char. There is many way to sort an array of number some are pretty fast but depends on what you're seeking. I think the fastest are insertion sort, bubble sort, or selection sort.

You can code them or find them already done in many languages.
There is other way to sort an array you can fin all of them here :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms